# How would I bind a keybind that uses Rubber to compile the current file on NvChad?

Tags: neovim, plugin-vim-latex, nvchad

I'm new to NvChad and would like to learn how to bind `<leader>t` to execute rubber on the current file.

My previous nvim setup had the code `nnoremap <leader>t :!rubber --pdf %<CR>`.

How would this carry over to NvChad?

Comment: If you have a solution you like feel free to publish it as an answer. You can also accept it two days later using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest.

Comment: Welcome to vi SE. Great you found a solution. However, I completely agree with Vivian that it belongs in an answer. Please scroll all the way down, paste your solution there and click "Post Your Answer". Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In the NvChad custom mapping file (`~/.config/nvim/lua/custom/mapping.lua`) edit the section `M.general`:

```lua
M.general = {
  n = {
    [";"] = { ":", "enter command mode", opts = { nowait = true } },
    ["<leader>s"] = { ":!rubber --pdf %<CR>", "rubber the current file", opts = { nowait = true } },
  },
}
```

More information about NvChad mapping in the [mapping documentation](https://nvchad.com/docs/config/mappings)

Remark: In the example I remap `<leader>s` (<kbd>Space</kbd>`s`) since `<leader>th` (<kbd>Space</kbd>`th`) is already mapped in NvChad.

Remark: You can list all the NvChad mapping with the `:Telescope keymaps` command

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting the `makeprg` and using `:make`, or writing a small compiler plugin (which sets `makeprg` and `errorformat`, and can be used with `:compiler`). See relevant help topics for details.